# What can and can't Form of Doom be combined with?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, psionics, meldshaping

The psionic power [*form of doom*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/formofDoom.htm) states:

> This power functions only while you inhabit your base form (for instance, you can’t be metamorphed or polymorphed into another form, though you can use *claws of the beast*, and *bite of the wolf* in conjunction with this power for your regular attacks), and while your mind resides within your own body.

Basically my question is, what counts as changing to a different form versus merely making modifications to my base form?

Do the totemist soulmelds that alter your form when bound to a chakra count as no longer residing in your base form, or would it be a situation similar to the [*claws of the beast*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/clawsoftheBeast.htm) allowance?

In a similar vein, would [*expansion*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/expansion.htm) be allowed?

Comment: Can you offer an example of such a soulmeld?

Comment: @HeyICanChan The Threefold Mask of the Chimera's totem chakra bind:  

"Your threefold mask is no longer just a mask—your head branches into the three monstrous heads of a chimera. Three pairs of eyes look out on the world at once, three heads direct your actions, and three sets of savage jaws slaver for prey"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is going to directly come out and say which it is; *form of doom* uses non-standard phrasing that basically isn’t really **used** anywhere else. That includes *Magic of Incarnum*, and even other psionic powers like *expansion*.

On the other hand, the example of *polymorph* or *metamorphosis* is pretty instructive: those things tell you to change into something else. Meanwhile, *claws of the beast* and *bite of the wolf* change something about you, but not the underlying creature. There is still a lot of room for uncertainty in particular corner cases, but I think that soulmelds and *expansion* are pretty clearly in the *claws of the beast* camp rather than the *metamorphosis* camp.

Ultimately: ask your DM, it’s ambiguous enough that you should run it by them, but I would be very surprised if any DM ruled that *expansion* or soulmelds ran afoul of *form of doom*.